# Issue with selection-box after changing font-size (fabrics.js, Text)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

i have come across an annoying bug in my fabric.js-editor:

The selection-box as well as the bounding area (the area you need to click on to select the object) are on the wrong position after changing the font-size of a text-object. (cf. images 1 & 2)

object-selection before:

[image]

object-selection after:

[image]

I would be very glad if someone knew how to fix this.
Thank you!

```js
canvas.on("object:selected", function(options) {
      document.getElementById("setFontSize").onclick = function handleFontSizeEdit() {
        canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontSize", document.getElementById("fontSize").value);
        canvas.renderAll();
      }
```

```html
Font-Size:
<input type="text" id="fontSize">
<input type="submit" id="setFontSize" value="Set">
```

Comment: That is a very strange situation. Could you add full code to have a working snippet?

Comment: Please don't add tags like "solved" to your question. Instead, accept the answer that helped you most. You can very well accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

I just realized that i was using an old version of fabric.js (1.1.0), after chanaging it to the current build (1.5) the problem with the selection box disappeared.

```
In case someone wants to see the code:
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGeaJj

Comment: Please add the important parts of your code directly into the answer. If you only provide a link to an external resource the answer becomes useless if that link dies someday.